# error in exporting glusterfs volume using samba/cifs

Tags: linux, centos, samba, cifs, glusterfs

I am trying to export glusterfs mount point as the samba export, and then mount it using CIFS protocol.

```
[root@ip-10-10-0-000 /]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1               7.8G  1.3G  6.5G  16% /
devtmpfs                 490M   56K  490M   1% /dev
tmpfs                    498M     0  498M   0% /dev/shm
10.00.0.00:/dist-volume   32G  130M   32G   1% /mnt/distributed
```

I have followed the below steps:

```
yum install samba
yum install samba-client
yum install cifs-utils
```

Added below lines to smb.conf file

```
[glustertest]

comment = For testing a Gluster volume exported through CIFS
path = /mnt/distributed
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

Started the smb service:

```
[root@ip-10-10-0-000 samba]# /etc/init.d/smb start
Starting SMB services:                                     [  OK  ]
```

when i try to mount it using the CIFS getting below error:

```
[root@ip-10-10-0-000 /]# mount.cifs -o username=user,password=userpwd 10.00.0.00:/dist-volume  /mnt/smb

mount.cifs: bad UNC (10.00.0.00:/dist-volume)
```

I am not sure,the steps I followed are fully correct I could not find any proper documentation for exporting gluster volumes using samba

can anyone please tell me what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i specified the volume name as "glustertest" i mentioned in samba.conf instead of using the actual gluster volume name it worked.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=userpwd \\\\127.0.0.1\\glustertest  /mnt/smb
```